# Using an NSTimer at high frequency's?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Hi I was just wondering, is an NSTimer running at 60Hz reliable?

I guess what I'm wondering is can an iPhone handle that? (I have an iPhone 4 btw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An NSTimer is useless approaching 30 milliseconds. If you're referring to 60 Hz as 60 times a second, means a 16.666 millisecond requirement. Also note, the closer you get to 30 milliseconds, the less accurate it is. That is, the more real time your requirements, the less accurate it is. A faster phone will not help this all that much.

What it sounds like you're doing is building a game of some sort, and you should look at using [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Comment: I'm actually calling a method that puts data through a Low Pass Filter. Would CADisplayLink work as well?

Comment: Probably will work just fine, though I've never tried using it for such a purpose.