# What is the fastest I should run an NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

What is the fastest I can run an NSTimer and still get reliable results? I've read that approaching 30ms it STARTS to become useless, so where does it "start to start becoming useless"...40ms? 50ms?

Comment: Fast running, repeating, timers should be avoided;  they tend to consume batter and leave your application unresponsive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an NSTimer at high frequency's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289588/using-an-nstimer-at-high-frequencys)

Comment: @bbum "fast running, repeating timers should be avoided"... are you referring to NSTimer instances, or as a design issue? Also, IS there a faster alternative to NSTimer? I need to go faster even than the CADisplayLink 60fps for pushing out MIDI.

Comment: @DanRosenstark Any type of polling should be avoided, if at all possible.  In your case, it may be unavoidable, though maybe there is some kind of means of buffering the data prior to the write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> the effective resolution of the time
>   interval for a timer is limited to on
>   the order of **50-100 milliseconds**

Sounds like if you want to be safe, you shouldn't use timers below 0.1 sec. But why not try it in your own app and see how low you can go?

You won't find a guarantee on this. NSTimers are opportunistic by nature since they run with the event loop, and their effective finest granularity will depend on everything else going on in your app in addition to the limits of whatever the Cocoa timer dispatch mechanisms are.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a recommended method to go faster than this, aside from writing my own using GCD?

Comment: @DanRosenstark (6 years later...) Depends on what you need it for. `CADisplayLink` seems like it might get you down to a 60th of a second, with some caveats around display timing since that's what it's for. If you need something guaranteed realtime, or super precise, you should ask a new question about how to best approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What's you definition of reliable?  A 16 mS error in a 1 second timer is under 2% error, but in a 30 mS timer is over 50% error.

NSTimers will wait for whatever is happening in the current run loop to finish, and any errors in time can accumulate.  e.g. if you touch the display N times, all subsequent repeating NSTimer firings may be late by the cumulative time taken by 0 to N touch handlers (plus anything else that was running at the "wrong" time).  etc.

CADisplayLink timers will attempt to quantize time to the frame rate, assuming that no set of foreground tasks takes as long as a frame time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of results you are trying to accomplish. [`NSTimer Class`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) `0.5 - 1.0` is a good place to start for reliable results.